# Swift - POST request recognises as GET on server

Tags: php, swift, post, afnetworking-2

Making a simple POST req from Swift to Apache/PHP.

Swift code:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://dzr.lenyapugachev.ru/createMember")!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let postString = "id=13&name=Jack"
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

     if error != nil {
         println("error=\(error)")
         return
     }

     println("response = \(response)")

     let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("responseString = \(responseString)")
}
task.resume()
```

PHP:

```
<?php

echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']."\n";
var_dump($_POST);

?>
```

Output:

```
GET
array(0) {}
```

So, it doesn't act as POST for server. I've also tried Alamofire and SwiftHTTP, same effect.

Please, good people, help.

Comment: Check with wireshark or something, but I almost guarantee that this code will result in a POST request being made to the server.  I'd guess something funky with redirects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed a HTTP POST request. Nothing wrong with your code. Using [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) (a HTPP debug proxy) I see that your request get redirected (301 HTTP)

**You need to fix your server's code / .httpaccess configuration**

Request:

```
POST /createMember HTTP/1.1
Host    dzr.lenyapugachev.ru
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length  15
Accept-Language en-us
Accept  */*
Connection  keep-alive
User-Agent  29530174/1 CFNetwork/711.2.23 Darwin/13.4.0
```

Response:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://dzr.lenyapugachev.ru/createMember/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

check your url
for PHP server it should be .Php file

used as 
`let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://dzr.lenyapugachev.ru/createMember.php")`!)

also if u send parameter your php server request like

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://dzr.lenyapugachev.ru/createMember.php?id=13&name=Jack")!)
```

refer this tutorial it include both php anD swift code to send post request [TUTORIAL: POST TO WEB SERVER API IN SWIFT USING NSURLCONNECTION](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-post-to-web-server-api-in-swift-using-nsurlconnection/)

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to put a slash in the end of address: url should be http://dzr.lenyapugachev.ru/createMember/ not /createMember

But, second part of ur answer isn't necessary, it's not get request. Anyway, thank you so much.